# what's the best way to share user data between components?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have a query i.e:

```
  query me {
    me {
      username
      email
    }
  }
```

now I need to share this data between components.

I guess I can:

- create HOC **withUserData** and wrap other components
- create a render prop component and wrap other components jsx

else?

Comment: We can also use Context API/Redux/Flux.

Comment: userData in particular seems to be something you want to keep in the app-state. This opens the door for creating functionality that should only be accessible for registered users. So yes, using something like Redux would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where are places you want to share them, I mean if you want to share data in the same branch of the component tree, you can have a **Container Component** at the top ( Which holds your state and pass the data has **props** to the levels below).

If your components branch is very **complex** and it needs to travel **down many levels** then its a pain and not recommended too, in this case, consider using Context API 
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

I would not recommend a **HOC** for this, HOC is not meant to share data, its meant to share re-useable **functionalities**.

Please check this, this has a bunch of best practices https://www.toptal.com/react/tips-and-practices

Well **REDUX** is another way but I would not recommend using REDUX looking at your need.

**When to use REDUX?**

Basically, you need to be using REDUX, when keeping the state in a top-level root component is no longer sufficient, like for example : ( you have two branches out from root component, one of the child components in branch **A** wants to access some state in branch **B**'s child, then you need to move it to the root component and again pass it down, such cases are apt for **REDUX** ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HOCs and Render props are not something that you would use to share data among components since each wrapper will have a different instance of the data whenever you create a component like

```
const MyComponentWithData = withUserData(MyComponent);
```

You would use HOCs and Render props mostly to provide a functionality which can be relevant to more than one components like `detecting click outside of the component`, or `a PrivateRoute for authentication` and so on.

However in order to share data you have options to use React Context, Flux or Redux. With the usage of React redux you can keep data in a store and read and update data from the components that want access to it. However if your app is not using Redux and you would want to share data only for a part of the application, you can simply make use of React Context. For more details on how to use it, you can read about it [`here`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#___gatsby)